# Proving a Weaker Version of Maximum Modulus Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a non-constant analytic $f: U \subset \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $U$ is open and connected. By analytic, I mean that $f$ has a local power series expansion. We are not yet allowed to assume that analytic and holomorphic are equivalent.

Let $z_0 \in U$ with $f(z_0) \neq 0$ and $s > 0$ so that the open ball $B(z_0,s)$ is a subset of $U$. I need to show that there exist $w_1, w_2 \in B(z_0,s)$ such that $|f(w_1)| > |f(z_0)| > |f(w_2)|$. We are not allowed to use Maximum Modulus Principle (hence the title of this post).

I was given the hint to use the fact (which I proved in a prior part) that on an open ball $B(z_0, r)$ with $r < s$, there exist an integer $k \geq 1$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ nonzero, and analytic $g: B(z_0, r) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ so that $$f(z) = f(z_0) + \lambda (z-z_0)^k + (z-z_0)^{k+1}g(z).$$
Using this fact, I am supposed to show that there is $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ so that
$$ |f(z_0) + \lambda te^{ik\theta} | = |f (z_0)| − t|\lambda| $$ for small $t \in (0, |\frac{f(z_0)}{\lambda}|)$
Then by considering  $f(z_0 + \epsilon e^{i\theta} )$ for small $\epsilon > 0$, I can find $w_2$. Supposedly, finding $w_1$ follows a similar method.

From the triangle inequality, it follows that $|f(z_0) + \lambda te^{ik\theta} | \geq |f (z_0)| − t|\lambda|$ follows for any $t > 0$. But I'm struggling to find a $\theta$ that attains equality for small $t$. Furthermore, even assuming this equality holds true, I'm struggling to see how considering $f(z_0 + \epsilon e^{i\theta} )$ gives us $w_2$. I've tried plugging in $z_0 + \epsilon e^{i\theta}$ into the $f(z)$ form that I previously proved, but I can't seem to get anything useful out of it. I would appreciate any hints.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for this well-written question! I think plugging in $z_0+\varepsilon e^{i\theta}$ is a promising idea: we get
\begin{align*}
f(z_0+\varepsilon e^{i\theta}) &= f(z_0) + \lambda (\varepsilon e^{i\theta})^k + (\varepsilon e^{i\theta})^{k+1} g(\varepsilon e^{i\theta}) \\
&= f(z_0) \biggl( 1 + \frac{\varepsilon^k}{f(z_0)} \bigl( \lambda e^{ik\theta} + \varepsilon e^{i(k+1)\theta} g(\varepsilon e^{i\theta}) \bigr) \biggr).
\end{align*}
Notice in particular that by choosing $\theta$ appropriately, you can make $\lambda e^{ik\theta}$ have any argument you want; in particular, you can make $\lambda e^{ik\theta}/f(z_0)$ a positive or negative real number as you wish.

The analytic function $g(z)$ will be bounded on any closed set contained in any neighborhood of $z_0$ on which it's defined. And there's that helpful extra factor of $\varepsilon$ in front of it. Can you finish from here?